# Converting the weight into thermal energy

Tags: thermodynamics, experimental-physics

Can we convert the weight into thermal energy? For example we would have a device like scale that if we stand on it, our weight can be converted into the thermal energy. Is this possible?

Comment: You mean like, instead of standing on a scale, we could step onto the top of a piston in a piston-cylinder assembly, thereby compressing the gas and increasing the thermal energy of the gas by doing work on it?  Alternatively, there are piezoelectric materials that generate a current when compressed. Is that the kind of thing you're talking about? Because "weight" is a force not an energy, so you can't convert it into thermal energy, but the weight can be made to do work on a system and hence change the energy of the system. Can you clarify?

Comment: Exactly what do you mean by "thermal energy". The term tends to be ambiguous as it is used to describe different things.

Comment: You can "convert" some form of energy into some other form of energy. Weight is a "force" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weight), not energy. However, you can convert the gravitational potential energy into "thermal energy" (heat). You just need something falling and some friction (e.g. a spacecraft/meteor heating up when entering the atmosphere, or a body sliding down an inclined plane with friction...).

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to convert your weight into heat, unless you were made of plutonium and fashioned into a bomb. when you blew up, a fraction of your *mass* (not weight) would be converted into heat.

Here is the closest you can come to this goal without using plutonium:

You climb a ladder to the top. at the bottom is a bucket of water with a propeller sticking into it, and a clever mechanism attached to a rope. By stepping off the ladder and grasping the rope, the mechanism lowers you slowly to the ground while spinning the propeller, which warms up the water slightly.

What you have done here is to store energy as *potential energy* associated with your height off the ground. you then convert it into *kinetic energy* of the spinning propeller, and then convert that into *heat* via friction in the water. *

Answer (score 1):

The term "thermal energy" is ambiguous. It has been alternatively (and often improperly) used in reference to temperature, heat, and molecular kinetic energy.

That said, weight is a force and force is not energy. However, if a weight results in the displacement or mechanical deformation of an object (does work), then the work done by the weight may generate heat if the deformation is inelastic, or the displacement otherwise involves friction.

With regard to your example of a weight scale, I suppose the generation of a small amount of heat is possible to the extent that inelastic deformation is involved when weighing an object. But I'm not familiar enough with their operation to know.

Hope this helps.